# The notification has no target applications

Tags: c#, windows, azure, push-notification, azure-notificationhub

I just started demo app for azure push notification. In my demo, I can broadcast notifications to all Windows devices but I want to send it individual user using tag. So I follow all the instructions and demo code from [Azure Notification Hubs Notify Users with .NET backend](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/notification-hubs/notification-hubs-aspnet-backend-windows-dotnet-wns-notification).

But I getting error while sending push notification for window and WP. Here is my code :

```
outcome = await Notifications.Instance.Hub.SendWindowsNativeNotificationAsync(toast, userTag);
```

I getting follwing error :

> The remote server returned an error: (400) Bad Request. The
>   notification has no target applications. The notification format is
>   windows. Review the credentials specified in the notification hub
>   description and the notification format.
>   .TrackingId:2aca8783-c5eb-41f8-a821-6f457806ca86_G7,TimeStamp:11/29/2016
>   1:40:07 PM

- I have not register my app on windows store. I guess it is creating problem but then why it is working for broadcast? When I send it individual user with tag then it gives above error.
- Please let me know where I am wrong. Is it necessary to register app on windows store for send notificaton with tag for single user?

Answer (score 0):

Have you gone through [Register your app for the Windows Store](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/notification-hubs/notification-hubs-windows-store-dotnet-get-started-wns-push-notification#register-your-app-for-the-windows-store) and [Configure your notification hub](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/notification-hubs/notification-hubs-windows-store-dotnet-get-started-wns-push-notification#configure-your-notification-hub)?

If so, does test send (from the portal) work? ([Here's an example](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/notification-hubs/notification-hubs-push-notification-fixer) how to do it from the classic Azure portal and Visual Studio, see "Verify message notifications" section.)

Are there any differences between the broadcast template and the one you use to send to individual users?

Comment: I have different template for broadcast and single user. But I did not register my app on widows store. SO first I think I need to register my app.

Answer (score 0):

According the logs, the Notification Hub you use does not have WNS credentials (Package SID and secret key) properly configured. While those credentials are required.

And it is also seen that no push notification were actually sent to devices, for last 7 days at least. So, maybe another Notification Hub was used for the broadcast, and that one has all the credentials in place...

Comment: No, I am using same notification hub for both one.